# Bootstrap 4: col-auto but not horizontally aligned

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to reproduce something like this using Bootstrap 4 and if possible without using jQuery: [What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QRge.png)

I'm using a PHP foreach to get values and then creating columns with col-auto. Thanks to that, all the columns have a size adjusted to content but the problem is that those are not horizontally aligned.
Here's what I have: [What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1RYm.png)

And here's my code (because of the PHP it will not work, but hopefully you'll understand it):

```css
.title {
    font-size: 0.75rem; /*12px*/
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #1C1B25;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.value {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #6846C6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <?php foreach($this->listEquations as $eq) { ?>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <p class="title"><?php echo $eq->name; ?></p>
      <p class="value"><?php echo $eq->value; ?></p>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: did you ever heard of `text-align`?

Comment: Yes, but I don't  see how it can help me. Can you develop ?

Comment: What do you mean with horizontally aligned? To both results seem pretty identical to each other with the exception of colors.

Comment: On the "What I want" screenshot, each "cell" is stack on top of another. On the "What I have" screenshot, the "cells" are not perfectly on top of each other (a sort of overlapping).

Comment: why not just give them a fixed width like col-3 or something? also please read [mcve] - you should paste your rendered html, not your php

Comment: This is possible using CSS-Grid **provided** the number of columns is known.

Comment: Yes, this what I did. But he problem of that method is that the col width is not adapted to the size of the content inside it. It's not perfect but that will do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try to give a fixed width rather than using col-auto.
The fixed width will horizontally align all the columns. As you wanted 6 columns in a row then you can use col-md-2/col-sm-2/col-lg-2

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach($this->listEquations as $eq) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                 <p class="title"><?php echo $eq->name; ?></p>
                 <p class="value"><?php echo $eq->value; ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what i did and I'll keep that solution even if it's not perfect because the width of the col is fixed and so, not adapted to the content size. Thank's!